# Этимология слова "вычурный"

Tags: этимология

Слово мне кажется русским (не иностранного происхождения), но не могу понять его происхождение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вычурный** - излишне затейливый, нарочито усложнённый, замысловатый.
Собственно русское слово. Образовано с помощью суффикса "-н" от "вычуры" (резные украшения > узоры > причуды), производного от несохранившегося "вычурить", являющегося приставочной формой к "чурить" - "готовить поделочный лес по изделиям".
Вычуры - 1) (разг.) сложные, замысловатые узоры на различных изделиях из дерева, железа, полотна; 2) нарочито замысловатые приёмы, средства, применяемые в целях более сильного воздействия на читателя, слушателя; вычурность в исполнении чего-либо.